# Задача для новчиков,но почему-то не работает

Tags: python

Даны три натуральных числа a, b, c, записанные в отдельных строках. Определите, существует ли неворожденный треугольник с такими сторонами.

Если треугольник существует, выведите строку YES, иначе выведите строку NO.
Вот сама задача.
Вот код-
`

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
if a + b > c and b + c > a or a + c > b:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

`
Что неверно?Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Возьмите каждое условие в скобки: if (a + b > c) and (b + c > a) ...

Comment: тут решение. гуглится первой же ссылкой.
https://younglinux.info/python/task/triangle

Comment: @AlexF под сомнением должно быть ``and`` ;)

Comment: @Эникейщик не and, а or ))

Answer (score 2):

Нужно все перевести в числовой тип данных int или float

Answer (score 1):

Ну, видимо, все логические операторы тут должны быть `and` и введённые данные надо привести в числовой формат.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
if a + b > c and b + c > a and a + c > b:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score -1):

`a = int(input())`                                   `#a = float(input())`
`b = int(input())`                                  `#b= float(input())`
`c = int(input())`                                     `#c= float(input())`
`if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:`
`print('Yes')`
`else:`
`print('No')`
Не забудь добавить 4 пробела после if и else